# Basic LISP Issue

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

So `(car '(2 3)) -> 2`

```
(cdr '(2 3)) -> (3)
```

Which function should I use to be able to get something to yield 3?

```
(function-name '(2 3)) -> 3
```

Comment: As posed, the question could also be answered `(defun foo (something) (declare (ignore something)) 3)`.

Comment: The very best explanation of how lists work internally (and therefor how to use car, cdr, cadr, ... I found in the old but excellent book Common Lisp: A gentle introduction to symbolic computation. http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dst/LispBook/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be fine to simply do:

```
(car (cdr '(2 3)))
```

Which is the same as:

```
(cadr '(2 3))
```

This works because "car" gets the first element in the expression, whereas cdr returns the remainder of the list, without the first element.  You've already shown that "(cdr '(2 3))" returns a list of "(3)".  Therefore, the "car" of this is the element (not the list), "3".  By the way, the "(cdr (cdr ('2 3)))" is the "(cdr (3))", which is "()".

Isn't LISP fun?

Comment: If you're going to answer his homework for him, you might as well explain why this works.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I didn't think of just running car on the single element.

Comment: No problem.  I've added additional explanation for clarification.

Comment: @Drew: To be clear, it helps to distinguish between running on an element and running on a list, even if that list has only a single element.  So when you mention "running car on the single element", you are actually "running car on a list that has a single element in it" (or the single element + the null list, "()", which is always there).

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

`car` refers to the first *element* in the list.

`cdr` refers to the *remainder* of the list, and is itself a list.

So what you need is a function that returns the first element from a list containing the last element.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `(second '(2 3))`.  `second` is another name for `cadr`.